# How do I format MS Excel 2016 to show 2 decimals that is always 00

Tags: excel-formula

Can I somehow format the number column in Excel 2016 to show 2 decimals and they should always be .00

Answer (score 2):

Go to Format Cell -> Number (Ctrl + 1) and give the cell the custom format of 0".00". You'll notice that whenever the underlying number is .50 or greater, it will round up. To avoid this, use a rounddown function.

Note though that you are basically cheating by showing significance that isn't there...

Comment: @RobinMackenzie - while I prefer a number format of `0\.\0\0`, there is no reason that `0".00"` will not work.

Comment: Nice one @Jeeped, had no clue it existed. Thanks!
The custom format in Excel is a great resource but a jungle all the same as there are remarkably few resources out there for enthusiasts.